# Java Reflection - Multidimensional Float Array Class

Tags: java, reflection

The code snippet below causes this warning in NetBeans 6.9.

```
[rawtypes] found raw type: org.openide.nodes.PropertySupport.Reflection
  missing type parameters for generic class org.openide.nodes.PropertySupport.Reflection<T>
```

```
Property dataProp = new PropertySupport.Reflection(t, dataStore.getFloat3DClass(),
                        workingData);

/**
 * Gets the Class object associated with the primitive 3d float array (i.e., float[][][]).
 *
 * @return  the Class object.
 */
public Class<?> getFloat3DClass()
{
    if (class3DFloat == null)
    {
       try
       {
           class3DFloat = Class.forName("[[[F");
       }
       catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
       {
           Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
       }
    }

    return class3DFloat;
}
```

At runtime `getFloat3DClass()` returns a `Class` object whose value is class `float[][][]`. How do I specify this at design time and avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working too hard. Don't use `dataStore.getFloat3DClass()` when you're making a `PropertySupport.Reflection`, use `float[][][].class` and it will work. And the value will be cached by the runtime for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a type parameter for Property and for PropertySupport. You could either use `<?>` or you could use `<float[][][]>`. If you do the latter there will be an unavoidable unchecked cast of the result from `Class.forName`:

```
Property<float[][][]> dataProp =
    new PropertySupport<float[][][]>.Reflection(t, dataStore.getFloat3DClass(),
                                                workingData);

...

public Class<float[][][]> getFloat3DClass() {
    ...
    if (class3DFloat == null)
    {
        try
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Class<float[][][]> tmp = (Class<float[][][]>)Class.forName("[[[F");
            class3DFloat = tmp;
        }
```

Comment: You're circumnavigating the world to get to next door. At the language level, `float[][][]` *is* a class name and supports the `class` pseudo-field.

Comment: That's true. I assumed that the code he provided was just to illustrate the problem he was having in his real code.